# STRING_SPLIT+JSON_VALUE not parsing data as valid JSON

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-cosmosdb

We have JSON data pulled from CosmosDB in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "TRFID": "001853",
        "Fields": {
            "FieldId": 32846,
            "FieldValue": "null"
        }
    },
    {
        "TRFID": "001865",
        "Fields": {
            "FieldId": 32846,
            "FieldValue": "[{\"id\":\"Boys\",\"text\":\"Boys\"},{\"id\":\"Mens\",\"text\":\"Mens\"}]"
        }
    },
    {
        "TRFID": "001880",
        "Fields": {
            "FieldId": 32846,
            "FieldValue": "[{\"id\":\"Boys\",\"text\":\"Boys\"},{\"id\":\"Girls\",\"text\":\"Girls\"},{\"id\":\"Babies\",\"text\":\"Babies\"},{\"id\":\"Pets\",\"text\":\"Pets\"},{\"id\":\"Others\",\"text\":\"Others\"}]"
        }
    }
]
```

When I invoke a `STRING_SPLIT` and a `JSON_VALUE` in my query, it returns 0 rows. I'm thinking the `\"` is possibly messing up the query in identifying whether the value is a valid JSON value or not, but when I load the data (without the `STRING_SPLIT` and `JSON_VALUE` clause) in SSMS the `\"` is not visible in the query:

[image]

I did invoke a `REPLACE` in my base query pulling the data from CosmosDB, and then in the CTE following that is where I invoke the `STRING_SPLIT` and `JSON_VALUE`. Does that mean that the `FieldValue` values are still not recognized as valid JSON data?

Edit: Query below

```
WITH CTE_Source AS (
    SELECT
        [TRFID]
        , [SectionId]
        , [rowtype]
        , [Fields]

    FROM OPENROWSET (
        ...
    ) AS CDB
    ),

    CTE_BaseMetadata AS (
    SELECT
        TRFID
        , FieldId
        , CASE
            WHEN FieldValue = '[{"id":"","text":""}]' THEN NULL
            WHEN FieldValue = 'null' THEN NULL
            WHEN FieldValue = '"null"' THEN NULL
            WHEN FieldValue = '""' THEN NULL
            WHEN FieldValue = '' THEN NULL
            WHEN FieldValue = '[]' THEN NULL
            ELSE FieldValue
            END AS FieldValue
    FROM CTE_Source

    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CTE_Source.Fields)
    WITH (
        FieldId VARCHAR(10) '$.FieldId'
        , FieldValue NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.FieldValue'
    ) AS CDB

    ),

    CTE_MultiJSONMetadata AS (
    SELECT
        TRFID
        , FieldId
        , FieldValue
        , split.Value
    FROM CTE_BaseMetadata

    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(JSON_VALUE(CTE_BaseMetadata.FieldValue, '$[0].FieldValue'), ',') AS split

    WHERE
        FieldId IN ('32846', '32847')
        AND FieldValue <> ''
    )

    SELECT * FROM CTE_MultiJSONMetadata
```

Comment: `FieldValue` stores a string (that in itself could be parsed as json as well - but it is just a string here)  - this string contains multiple `"` as part of its text - that is why they are masked by prefixing with `\\` - it just means "take the following char as _literal_ not as whatever its special meaning (terminating  the earlier " ) is. Not sure waht you meant to do with string_split and json_value

Comment: Your json seems valid - use a google "json validator" to find one to check it. You probably need to give more context as to what your problem is.

Comment: What is your current attempt and how exactly do you use `STRING_SPLIT()` and `JSON_VALUE()`?

Comment: I've added the query I'm using to the question

Comment: Why does `FieldValue` contain a string instead of an array, or any other JSON value? *All* JSON parsers would have trouble with this thing. That's a bug with whatever produced the JSON text, not JSON_VALUE or OPENJSON. It's infinitelyl cheaper and easier to solve that bug instead of trying to reverse it. Why not use `"FieldValue": [{"id":"Boys","text":"Boys"},{"id":"Mens","text":"Mens"}]` ?

Comment: That's how our devs made it unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The data, stored in the `Fields` part is a valid JSON content stored as a string, not as a JSON array. So, I'm not sure why do you need to use `STRING_SPLIT()` and `JSON_VALUE()`, a combination of `OPENJSON()` and an `APPLY` operator is enough:

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[
    {
        "TRFID": "001853",
        "Fields": {
            "FieldId": 32846,
            "FieldValue": "null"
        }
    },
    {
        "TRFID": "001865",
        "Fields": {
            "FieldId": 32846,
            "FieldValue": "[{\"id\":\"Boys\",\"text\":\"Boys\"},{\"id\":\"Mens\",\"text\":\"Mens\"}]"
        }
    },
    {
        "TRFID": "001880",
        "Fields": {
            "FieldId": 32846,
            "FieldValue": "[{\"id\":\"Boys\",\"text\":\"Boys\"},{\"id\":\"Girls\",\"text\":\"Girls\"},{\"id\":\"Babies\",\"text\":\"Babies\"},{\"id\":\"Pets\",\"text\":\"Pets\"},{\"id\":\"Others\",\"text\":\"Others\"}]"
        }
    }
]'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT j1.TRFID, j1.FieldId, j2.id, j2.text
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
  TRFID nvarchar(6) '$.TRFID',
  FieldId int '$.Fields.FieldId',
  FieldValue nvarchar(max) '$.Fields.FieldValue'
) j1
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(CASE WHEN j1.FieldValue <> 'null' THEN j1.FieldValue END) WITH (
  id nvarchar(50) '$.id',
  text nvarchar(50) '$.text'
) j2
```

Result:

| TRFID | FieldId | id | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001853 | 32846 | *null* | *null* |
| 001865 | 32846 | Boys | Boys |
| 001865 | 32846 | Mens | Mens |
| 001880 | 32846 | Boys | Boys |
| 001880 | 32846 | Girls | Girls |
| 001880 | 32846 | Babies | Babies |
| 001880 | 32846 | Pets | Pets |
| 001880 | 32846 | Others | Others |

Comment: > The data, stored in the Fields part is a valid JSON content stored as a text, not as JSON array <

Was this the reason why the data was not being parsed properly by JSON_VALUE? Also, why `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY`?

Comment: @MiloUlver, 1) `JSON_VALUE()` extracts a scalar value from given JSON content, if you want to extract a JSON object you need `JSON_QUERY()` and 2) With `OUTER APPLY`  each row from the left table expression (first `OPENJSON()` call) will present in the result irrespective of its match with the right table expression (second `OPENJSON()` call).

Comment: @MiloUlver, if I understand the example correctly, a possible reason for this `null` result is a wrong path expression: `SELECT JSON_VALUE('[{"id":"Boys","text":"Boys"},{"id":"Girls","text":"Girls"}]', '$[0].FieldValue')` vs `SELECT JSON_VALUE('[{"id":"Boys","text":"Boys"},{"id":"Girls","text":"Girls"}]', '$[0].id')`.